# Detail view in Visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

I have a detail view control in my aspx form.
I have the following field in my detail view:
NameId
Name
ContactNo

But i dont want to allow the user to edit the "NameId" field.
So i set it as READ ONLY and INSERT VISIBLE.
But setting it dosent allow me to update.
If all the fields are set to be allow for editing, the update work successfully.

How should i go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to pass that NameID field in the `UpdateCommand`?

Setting the field to `ReadOnly=True` won't pass the value to the underlying datasource.  So you may need to remove that field from the `UpdateCommand`.

See this link for some more information:

http://weblogs.asp.net/istofix/archive/2008/12/31/tips-amp-tricks-details-view-and-read-only-fields.aspx

Comment: Hmm.. Is like i have a total of 4 fields in my database.
NameId, Name, ContactNo, Date
Original record: 1, hihi, 5556789, 121012
Edited input: 1, hihi, 12345, 120091

Such as the user will not be allowed to edit the NameId and Name fields

Comment: Right, you don't want them to edit NameID or Name, correct?  

Anything you have set to ReadOnly=True shouldn't be in the UpdateCommand statement.  Because "ReadOnly=True" will pass only NULLs to the UpdateCommand.